# How to Automatically Manage a LARGE Number of Views Pages Under ONE?

Tags: views

I am developing a website for a school's Alumni Association that has been around since the 1800s. Every student has a Grad Class specified in the database:

e.g. /students/1947/John_Doe (indicates graduated in 1947; all of this is ready to go).

But now I want to create a page for every year (1890, 1891, ... 1970, 1971, etc.) and have each listed on that page:

e.g. /students/1947 (would list all students who graduated in 1947)

Using Contextual Filters, this is easy!! But the problem is that creating each individual page for each individual year would be extremely cumbersome. Do each of these pages needed to be created manually (with an identical Contextual Filter) or is there a way to automatically manage all of these graduation classes under a single view? If so, how would those pages be created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to add a wildcard to the URL pattern of your view like `/students/%` and then use this as argument for the contextual filter.

Similar to how the default "Taxonomy term" view does it (screenshot attached):

[image]